# Windows 10 quick access links docfile corrupted

Tags: windows

In Windows 10, my quick access links have been broken for a while. I upgraded to the Pro Insider build 17025 and now get a new error "The docfile has been corrupted"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alexander_ALX on Microsoft dev forums.

Type cmd in search bar, right click on Command Prompt and Run as Administrator

Run this:
del %appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\automaticdestinations*

Close all File Explorers. When you re-open a fresh one, Quick Access will be alive again with the default settings and you can now pin folders to it